# Spring integration- Route one channel to specific channel with message transformer

Tags: spring, spring-integration

am new to Spring Integration

my objective is passing message to one channel to another (chain process)

Channel1 ---> chennal2 --> chennal3 ---> chennal4.
(Msg1)       (Msg2)                (Msg3)                    (Msg4)

\                         \                       /                          /

\                        \                   /                          /

errorChennal (Msg5)

1.       Msg1(EmployeeObject), Msg2 (DetailsObjet), Msg3(VerificationObject), Msg4(FinalObject), Msg5(ErrorObject)

```
    Each channel payloads will have different Class Objects.
```

2. All the channel need to be communicated to "errorChennal" in case of Exception, validation error, etc.

Tried:
1. when I tried with @transformer am not able to communicate to "erroeChannel".

2. when I tried with @Router(header-value-router) Message transform not happing. Msg1 object is to all object

Question:
  How do i route one channel to specific channel with message transformer?

**FOUND ANSWER**

```
Configuration:

<int:channel id="channel1"/>
<int:channel id="channel2"/>
<int:channel id="channel3"/>
<int:channel id="channel4"/>

<int:service-activator input-channel="channel1" ref="firstChannel" method="doProcess1" />
<int:service-activator input-channel="channel2" ref="secondChannel" method="doProcess2" />
<int:service-activator input-channel="channel3" ref="thirdChannel" method="doProcess3" />
<int:service-activator input-channel="channel4" ref="forthChannel" method="doProcess4" />
<int:service-activator input-channel="errorChannel" ref="errorHandlerChannel" method="doErrorProcess" />

Java Code: 

public FirstChannel {

    private Map<String, MessageChannel> msgChannels;
    boolean isError = false;
    @Autowired
    public ScheduleParser(Map<String, MessageChannel> msgChannels) {
        super();
        this.msgChannels = msgChannels;
    }

    public void doprocess1(Message<?> message){
    File file = (File) message.getPayload();
    //business code 

    if(!isError)
        //transforming the messae
        msgChannels.get("channel2").send(new GenericMessage(EmployeeVO , headersMap));
    else 
        msgChannels.get("errorChannel").send(new GenericMessage(ObjectVO , headersMap));
}
```

}

Same way Other channels Code will be

Answer (score 0):

Channels aren't connected to each other they are connected to endpoints.

Transformers don't route, routers route.

You need something like

```
channel1->payload-type-router

type1Channel->...
type2Channel->...
...
```

possibly with a different transformer for each payload type downstream.

It's generally better to show the configuration you have tried rather than some abstraction like you have shown.

The error flow configuration depends on what starts your flow (gateway, poller, etc) - i.e. what is upstream of `channel1`.

**EDIT**

Your configuration is completely wrong. For example, you currently have two subscribers on `channel1` - a header value router and service activator.

Messages arriving on `channel1` will alternately go to one or the other - messages going to the service activator will **never** go to the router.

Without knowing the complete picture, I am guessing you need something like...

```
channel1->serviceActivator1->channel1toRouter->router(channel2 or failed)
channel2->serviceActivator2->channel2toRouter->router(channel2 or failed)
...
```

Comment: See my edit - you should also edit your question instead of providing more information in another answer.

Comment: Hi Gray, thanks for you reply, actually am new to spring and posting, here after will do the same
 . 
I have found some solution and updated in question block  for the same. Is that thhe best way.